# Regular expression to match text that doesn't start with substring?

Tags: regex

I have text with file names scattered throughout. The filenames appear in the text like this:

```
|test.txt|
|usr01.txt|
|usr02.txt|
|foo.txt|
```

I want to match the filenames that don't start with `usr`. I came up with `(?<=\|).*\.txt(?=\|)` to match the filenames, but it doesn't exclude the ones starting with `usr`. Is this possible with regular expressions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(?<=\|)(?!usr).*\.txt(?=\|)
```

You were nearly there :)

Now you have a positive lookbehind, and a positive and negative lookahead.

Comment: I struggled for a while using just one look-behind with this..  the trick was to use a combo. Well done sir.

Answer (score 1):

With python

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> x="""|test.txt|
... |usr01.txt|
... |usr02.txt|
... |foo.txt|
... """
>>>
>>> re.findall("^\|(?!usr)(.*?\.txt)\|$",x,re.MULTILINE)
['test.txt', 'foo.txt']
```

Answer (score -1):

```
grep -v "^|usr" file

awk '!/^\|usr/' file

sed -n '/^|usr/!p' file
```